# Why does this first code-snippet cause image.onload to fire, but the second does not?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

```
function SetImage(planViewCanvas, context, componentID) {
    var img = new Image();

    img.onload = function () {
        alert("Fired!!");
        planViewCanvas.width = img.width;
        planViewCanvas.height = img.height;
        context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
        $('#NoPlanViewImage').hide();
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: '../PlanView/RenderFloorPlanImage',
        data: { ComponentID: componentID },
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function (imageSource) {
            if (imageSource !== "") {
                img.src = '../PlanView/RenderFloorPlanImage?ComponentID=' + componentID;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

This causes img.onload to trigger. Yet:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '../PlanView/RenderFloorPlanImage',
    data: { ComponentID: componentID },
    datatype: 'json',
    success: function (imageSource) {
        if (imageSource !== "") {
            img.src = imageSource;
        }
    }
});
```

Modifying the ajax request s.t. I set the src to the data returned is a no go. I would like to set the image without having to go back to my controller a second time, but I would also like to fire the onload event once the image is fully loaded. How is this achievable?

```
    public ActionResult RenderFloorPlanImage(int componentID)
    {
        PlanViewComponent planViewComponent = PlanViewServices.GetComponentsForPlanView(componentID, SessionManager.Default.User.UserName, "image/png");

        MemoryStream memoryStream = null;

        if (!Equals(planViewComponent, null))
        {
            FloorPlan floorPlan = GetDesktopFloorPlan(planViewComponent);

            // get the floor plan for the desktop...
            if (!Equals(floorPlan, null) && !Equals(floorPlan.Image, null) && floorPlan.Image.Length > 0)
            {
                memoryStream = new MemoryStream(floorPlan.Image);
            }
        }

        return !Equals(memoryStream, null) ? File(memoryStream, "image/png") : null;
    }
```

I guess a better question might be "How do I load a File into an image?" It seems to be done automatically for me when I set the src attribute, but not automatically when I get a handle on the result.

Comment: is `imageSource` a proper URI? If it is a 404, it will not fire an `onload` I guess, and judging from what you shared, I'd assume it to be an object and not even a string.

Comment: Sorry, I just added in the controller action. I am returning a File object.

Comment: Try a `console.log(imageSource)`. Sure you have a valid *JSON* object? If you are trying to send binary data, this will be really tricky. You need some Base64 encoding.

Comment: console.log makes an attempt to spit out a PNG file. My console is filled with non-renderable ascii characters.

Comment: Raw PNG data is not valid for the `src=` attribute. It is meant to be set to a URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're streaming the binary of the image. That cannot be set as the SRC in an AJAX call. The server will send out a MIME type, then stream the file. The Ajax call is expecting a PATH, then the browser will grab the file by itself.

i.e. the request expects text/HTML as a response, but gets an unexpected image MIME header + binary data instead.

Comment: Indeed. Do you know if its best practice to set the src directly? The issue here is that I do not want to always return an image, but I have no way of nicely detecting that the controller returned null if I automatically try and drop the return value into src.

Comment: What would you return other than an image?

Comment: The server is being given an ID, and it is looking for a floor plan associated with that ID. Instead of having to find a way to set a 'default' image for ID's without a floor plan, I wanted to simply show/hide a warning on the page. imageSource is equal to "" when I return null from RenderFloorPlanImage.

Comment: Best to send back: '../PlanView/RenderFloorPlanImage?ComponentID=1234'. Check for valid IDs. Send back the placeholder URL if you don't find it.

Comment: That does not seem correct to me... If I am going out to the server once -- the server should not return a path back to itself which the img will need to follow to retrieve the image. That's extra RTT when the server could just be returning a compressed image. Am I following you incorrectly?

Comment: AJAX expects TEXT - as Anthony says, you can send BASE64, otherwise it's regular old HTML.

Comment: Any thoughts on which is less ugly? I am leaning towards yours. I think two hits on the server, while slightly slower, would result in more clear code than encoding/decoding + serialization time.

Comment: I agree. Plus Base-64 is pretty fat compared to binary.

Answer (score 1):

**Your browser could *not load* the image, so no `onload` is triggered.**

The `src=` attribute must be set to a valid *URI*, not raw png data. Think of what would happen to the HTML file if you put in the raw PNG file there. No wonder it breaks.

You can to some extend cheat here by Base64-encoding the image and using a so called `data:` url. I'm not sure how well the cross-browser support for this is. From what I read, internet explorer <= 7 will *not* work.

Comment: How can I determine that src is going to return a valid image without hitting the server twice, though?

Comment: It looks to me as if you can just load the image and wait for the `onload` to be triggered or a timeout to occur (when the src is not valid).